# Function that return the numbers of prime numbers strictly less than n

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def estDiviseur(i,n):
    return n%i==0

def estPremier(n):
    b=0
    if n==1:
        return False
    for i in range(1 , n+1):
        if estDiviseur(i,n)==True:
            b=b+1
    if b>2:
            return False
    else:
            return True

def nbPremiers(n):
    c=0
    for i in range(0,n):
        if estPremier(i)==True:
            c=c+1
    return c
```

problem is with nbPremiers, if n = 2  it returns to me 2 when it should be 0. the 2 first functions are right and they work exactly as i wanted to. last one is to count the numbers of primal numbers stricly less than n.

Comment: BTW, it's generally better to write `if some_condition:` instead of `if some_condition == True:`. See [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had several mistakes in your code; one of which was getting confused with `i` and `n` - using better names for parameters will help you.

Note that `0`, and '1' are not primes.

```
def est_diviseur(diviseur, n):
    return n % diviseur == 0

def est_premier(n):
    b = 0
    if n < 2:
        return False
    for diviseur in range(1, n+1):
        if est_diviseur(diviseur, n) == True:
            b = b + 1
    if b > 2:
            return False
    else:
            return True

def nb_de_premiers_inferieurs_a(nombre):
    """retourne le nombre de nombres premiers inferieurs a n
       returns the number of primes whose value is lower than n
    """
    compteur = 0
    for n in range(nombre):
        if est_premier(n):
            compteur += 1
    return compteur

for n in range(20):
    print(n, est_premier(n), nb_de_premiers_inferieurs_a(n))
```

#### output:

```
0 False 0
1 False 0
2 True 0
3 True 1
4 False 2
5 True 2
6 False 3
7 True 3
8 False 4
9 False 4
10 False 4
11 True 4
12 False 5
13 True 5
14 False 6
15 False 6
16 False 6
17 True 6
18 False 7
19 True 7
```

Comment: for _ in range(20)
? That's not an unused variable, so name it.

Comment: Ninja'd. FWIW, I suggest that it's better to use English names rather than French, since it makes it easier for the international community. And I'd probably simplify that final `b` stuff in `est_premier` to `return b <= 2`

Comment: 2 is a prime number

Comment: Named the variable, good point. Added translation. & corrected 2. Thanks for your constructive remarks.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! but finally the problem was just : if est_premier(n),  its if est_premier(i)  and everything is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

All those functions can be written as one-liners:

```
from math import sqrt

def is_divisor(i,n):
    return n % i == 0

def is_prime(n):
    return n >= 2 and not any(is_divisor(i, n) for i in range(2,int(sqrt(n)) + 1))

def primes_count(n):
    return sum(1 for x in range(2,n+1) if is_prime(x))

print(primes_count(100))
# 25
```

Whichever country you're coming from, it's usually a good idea to write function names in English, especially if you're asking questions on an internation, english-speaking website.

Note that you only need to check divisors between 2 and `sqrt(n)`.

A more efficient way would be to use the [sieve of Erathostenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Finally, this [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) is usually defined for primes lower than or equal to `n`.